# sql while loop duplicating results

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop

I have a rather large and complex query to work out people in work, off sick etc. This worked great if I want to just see it for 1 day, however I need to allow users to view multiple days.

I added a startdate and enddate parameter and looked at building in a sql while loop to change the start date each time and write the values into a temp table so I can pull them out at the end. This may not be the best approach.

I have got the loop working, however it keeps duplicating the results like in the example below:

How the data should look:

> Date:        Value
>
> 01/01/2014    1
>
> 02/01/2014    2
>
> 03/01/2014    3

How data is being exported:

> Date:        Value
>
> 01/01/2014    1
>
> 02/01/2014    1
>
> 02/01/2014    2
>
> 03/01/2014    1
>
> 03/01/2014    2
>
> 03/01/2014    3

This is the example of the loop I found and I have used with my own sql code in the middle. My sql code only uses the startdate parameter being passed in.

Should I be using a different type of loop maybe, or have I missed something out to stop the duplication? Any suggestions welcome as im not sure how to stop the loop doing this. It is bring back the correct data I just need to exclude the duplicates.

Structure of my code and loop but not the full example as code in middle is very long:

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable1
(
Date DATETIME
Value int
);


declare @startdate datetime
declare @enddate datetime

while @startdate <= @enddate

BEGIN

(My Sql Code is placed here and uses the @startdate parameter)

INSERT INTO #TestTable1(Date, value)
select * from (uses allot of temp tables and cte from the code i have used.)


SET @startdate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startdate)
END 


select * from #TestTable1

drop table #TestTable1
```

Comment: Try `<` instead of `<=` because that overlap the resutls.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work its still duplicating

Comment: You should try to include simplified code to reproduce the result, right now my guess is that this `select * from (uses allot of temp tables and cte from the code i have used.)` is responsible for your duplicates (maybe some kind of cross join or sth. like that going on in there?)

Comment: Why not use a WHERE clause here .. 

   " INSERT INTO #TestTable1(Date, value)
select * from (uses allot of temp tables and cte from the code i have used.) " 

at the end of the SELECT clause... "WHERE DATE BETWEEN (@startdate AND  @enddate)" .. Something like that . you don't have to use WHILE if you did that.

Comment: Thanks for both replies, I will try the between and amending the query

Comment: The between start and end dates didn't work didn't work I ended up getting more rows and the sql at the end should only be picking out results for the start date the loop should be looking at, if I enter a date manually it works and dosent get any duplicate info so not sure why its picking up the day befores results each time but I will have a play with the last statement but any other suggestions would be very welcome